# Getting `Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2 (BUS_ADRERR)` when enumerating next element in ZipFile.entries

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, crash, zip

I am trying to open a ZipFile to iterate its entries, modify an entry and write contents to ZipOutputStream.

Below is the code to do that (Simplified to show only the problematic part)

```
        val filePath = fileAsset.file.absolutePath
        val zipFile = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            ZipFile(filePath)
        }
        val zos = ZipOutputStream(withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            FileOutputStream(filePath)
        });
        val e = zipFile.entries()
        while (e.hasMoreElements()){
            val entryIn = e.nextElement();
        }
```

But this gives me following Error
`Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2 (BUS_ADRERR), fault addr 0x75087e3fe43f in tid 10770 (DefaultDispatch), pid 10144 (ple.ebookreader)`  and the app crashes.

Also:

The Zip file is readable as Plain `File` object. Problem occurs when constructing `ZipFile`

It occurs when i call `e.nextElement()` before that everything is totally fine.

So far i've tried using `zipFile.stream`, converting `entries` to `List`, but i couldn't find the issue.

Can you tell me why i'm getting this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out,

The problem was that i'm creating `ZipFile` and `ZipOutputStream` with same path

I created `ZipOutputStream` with a bytes array and crash has stopped occuring.

```
            val bytesStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            val zos = ZipOutputStream(bytesStream);
```